# Extract part from string

Tags: python

How to extract `text1__text2_text3_text4_text5` from string `text1__text2_text3_text4_text5_text6`?
I have tried like this (this gives text6 that I'm not interested in), but can't get the correct result:

```
y = text1__text2_text3_text4_text5_text6
z = y.split('_')[6]
```

Can anyone help (preferably without using regex)?

Comment: you can replace `_text6` with ``

Comment: If you do y.split('_') you get a list of all the text you have (+ a '' due to the double underscore)
So showing all except the last one is y[:-1]

Comment: `'text1__text2_text3_text4_text5_text6'.rsplit('_', 1)[0]`

Comment: You didn't mention your criteria, which we can only guess is "remove" the last `_` part. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing *the* position instead of accessing *till* the position.

```
y = "text1__text2_text3_text4_text5_text6"
z = y.split('_')[:6]
print("_".join(z))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following:

```
y = "text1__text2_text3_text4_text5_text6"
z = y.rsplit("_", 1)[0]
```